# Google Maps: How to add multiple markers to google maps

Tags: google-maps, swift3, google-places-api

I searched a lot but didn't get any exact solution for my question with Swift 3 context. I need to plot multiple markers (of type GMSMarker) in my application. My code is as below.

```
var markerDict: [Int: GMSMarker] = [:]
var custlatt = [13.093781,13.034893,13.034893]
var custlong = [77.576284,77.596372, 77.596372]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 0...2{
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude:custlatt[i], longitude: custlong[i], zoom: 10.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        view = mapView

        markerDict[i] = GMSMarker()
        markerDict[i]?.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:custlatt[i], longitude: custlong[i])
        markerDict[i]?.title = "NAGAVARA"
        markerDict[i]?.snippet = "Bengaluru"
        markerDict[i]?.map = mapView
    }
```

Even though I'm using array of marker only one position (last value of custlatt,custlong array) is being marked. Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong? Or is there any other method of implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Where you have

```
markerDict[0] = GMSMarker()
```

shouldn't that be

```
markerDict[i] = GMSMarker()
```

for that and the next 4 lines?

I imagine the reason that you only see the last marker is that the previous ones get garbage-collected since you overwrite the only reference to them on the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I edited the question by placing  markerDict[i] = GMSMarker(). But still I'm not getting, if you have sample code repo can you add the link here.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate GmsMapview outside the for loop solve your problem!!!

```
class MapVC:UIViewController{

    var markerDict: [String: GMSMarker] = [:]
    var custlatt = [13.093781,13.034893,13.034893]
    var custlong = [77.576284,77.596372, 77.596372]
    var mapView:GMSMapView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView = GMSMapView()
    mapView.frame = self.view.frame
    setupViews()
    for (i, element) in (["first","second","third"]).enumerated(){
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude:custlatt[i], longitude: custlong[i], zoom: 10.0)
        mapView.camera = camera

        markerDict[element] = GMSMarker()
        markerDict[element]?.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:custlatt[i], longitude: custlong[i])
        markerDict[element]?.title = element
        markerDict[element]?.snippet = element
        markerDict[element]?.map = mapView
}
    }
```